# install cakephp on subdomain

Tags: cakephp, subdomain

i want to install a cakephp app on a subdomain (shared hosting).
my subdomain public_html:

```
/domains/domain.com/public_html/mycake
```

and domain public_html:

```
/domains/domain.com/public_html
```

any changes in files needed?
where do i have upload files (app, cake, webroot)?

thanks for your quick answer ... (i've read that [article](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/gedm/2009/08/29/installing-cakephp-on-shared-hosting), but i can't understand it).

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the root files (app, cake, webroot…) and place them at the root of your subdomain.
Any .htaccess (Apache)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, put everything in public_html/mycake.  Then you can go to mycake.domain.com and it should work (as long as subdomain is configured).  I have several cakephp installations on subdomains.